# Field name does not appear on highlights panel of lightning app builder?

Tags: lightning, app-builder, flexipages, lightning-app-builder

I want to display number of open cases on Contact highlights panel. I used lightning app builder for it. Here I have renamed Contact object as Member. I inserted the field 'Open Cases' in compact layout, but the title 'Open Cases' does not appear (as shown in first image). Just the number of open cases is displayed. Later I inserted two fields (Name and Closed Cases) and now the title appears (as shown in second image). Is there any way I could display Open cases along with title without displaying the name on the highlights panel? Any help is appreciated.

[image: In this image, I do not get title 'Open Cases']

[image: In this image, I get title 'Open Cases']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, what you are trying to get is `label` and not `title`. Title is something which comes as pop-up near mouse pointer when you place mouse on a field for more than like 2 sec (or 3sec appx.)

As a standard, you will get the object label in top of highlights panel - below which you can place 5 fields (for which labels are also displayed). But, you cannot show the label of the field in 1st row.

So, you can name it as `Open Cases` instead of `Member` to get the label of object - but I think this is totally undesirable.